# set div width to content without inline-block

Tags: css

I want to set the width of divs to their contents and keep the divs under each other.  Using `display:inline-block` effectively floats the divs next to each other.  How can I do this?

Comment: insert `<br />` among them?

Comment: Just remove inline-block. Or set them to width: 100%

Comment: Use display:block;
width:100%

Comment: While BR tag will work, this is not a good method as there is no way to determine the amount of line space or padding the BR will induce between browsers. Clear:both is the semantic CSS solution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ghJZn/1/)**

Consider the following markup:

```
<div class="text">apple</div>
<div class="text">banana</div>
<div class="text">kiwi</div>
<div class="text">orange</div>
```

Float and clear all, here is the CSS:

```
.text {
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: The poster of this question wants the display inline property hence wanting the box to be the size of its content. They should only have to use clear both.

Comment: @JudsonTerrell How you would set the `width` of a `block` element to the width of the content within it? You must explicitly make it `inline` or `inline-block`, or make it `float`, or change the `position` of it to `absolute`. If they aren't floated, so clear is useless.

Comment: I meant along with inline block. Another option is to put a div between them with only clear both.

Comment: @JudsonTerrell `float` property will do nothing with `inline-block` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Put clear: both on them this will keep them from floating, and yes you do need float "something"

```
#div1, #div2{

    display: inline;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid grey;

}

<div id="div1">some content here that is bigger</div>
<div id="div2">some content here</div>
```

Comment: Yep, NOX's solution works fine setting the div width to the contents without using inline-block.

Comment: Mmm...what if I want the divs to be center aligned?  I'll post another question...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805802/set-div-width-to-content-without-inline-block-and-keep-divs-under-each-other-cen