# set div width to content without inline-block and keep divs under each other center aligned

Tags: css

I want some divs to get their width from their content.  Display:inline-block does this, but I also want the divs to be under each other, not next to each other as floated.

Using float:left instead of inline-block does this, but I want the divs to be center aligned, not left aligned.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on the parent div put white-space: pre-line; 
on the child divs add clear : both

```
#wrapper{ text-align: center; white-space: pre-line; }
#div1, #div2{

    display: inline-block;    
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 3px auto 3px auto;
    width: auto;

}

<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="div1" class="clearfix">some content here that is bigger</div>
     <div id="div2" class="clearfix">some content here</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/judsonmusic/8HCWp/

Comment: Nice solution, but `pre-line` will make it difficult to keep the HTML markup clear, for example if you insert some empty lines between your `div1` and `div2` tags, the view will be harmful. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HCWp/2/).

Comment: True, but I also dont make a habit of leaving that much space between lines of code haha. But true. Looks like you win this one.

Comment: I can see that this solution works with borders, whereas NOX's solution there is a problem with rendering borders.  I'll just have to be aware of space between lines of code!

Comment: Just wanted to mention that another solution would be to wrap individual span tags around each text allowing the span to have the border while the div has block and clear. It would be a little more code but more "solid" approach.

Answer (score 3):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tktAz/)**

Consider the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">apple</div>
    <div class="text">banana</div>
    <div class="text">kiwi</div>
    <div class="text">orange</div>
</div>
```

Because you want to `align` your elements, you must use `inline`, then we will break
them with `:after`:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.text {
    background: yellow;
    display: inline;
}

.text:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a bug in IE8 with the content property?

Comment: Maybe, I don't test it, but as you see, the question is tagged with CSS3 `;)`.

Comment: I can see that your fiddle works, but there is a problem with borders and padding See http://jsfiddle.net/uvSfK/

Comment: @PeterBrowne So you should change your markup, I think. Put an `span` inside your `div`s and style it, check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvSfK/1/).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319794/make-flex-children-inline-block), there's also a flex solution to this problem:

```css
#container > p {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
    
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>A text</p>
  <p>A text</p>
  <p>A longer text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

html is

```
<div>
   abc <div style="margin:4px auto;width:100px;">div1</div><br/>
   abc <div style="margin:4px auto;width:100px;">div1</div><br/>
   abc <div style="margin:4px auto;width:100px;">div1</div><br/>
   abc <div style="margin:4px auto;width:100px;">div1</div><br/>
</div>
```

and style sheet is

```
div{
    border:1px solid;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
   }
```

check demo at http://jsfiddle.net/xupHN/