# Make flex children inline-block

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to have the flex children rendered `inline-block` so that `border-bottom` is under the `li`'s width instead of the container's width.

Apparently flex children can't be set as inline-block?

Is there a workaround to this problem?

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Tab 1</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/joshuajazleung/pen/EbwZmJ

Comment: If you set it as inline-block then it will no longer be flex. Your question makes no sense written like that.

Comment: @Rob If to set `inline-block` to a _flex item_ won't make it _"no longer be flex"_, though it won't give the expected result.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Add `align-items: flex-start` to the container:

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: flex-start; /* NEW */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu > li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Tab 1</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
```

OR... switch from `display: flex` to `display: inline-flex`.

```css
.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu > li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Tab 1</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
```

More details here: [Make flex items take content width, not width of parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40141163/3597276)

Comment: Very good use of flex, I encountered an identical problem today where I have to inline a flex-child. In that case, I used align-self: flex-start property.